# FAB appears before PageLoad

Tags: android, webview

I am making a webview app..
made a FAB using the Design Library and hide it via xml i.e. android:visibility="Gone"
and set it visible after PageLoad i.e. in the onPageFinished method...
But the FAB appears even the page isnt loaded..
I also use onReceivedError and display an Error.Html

Comment: put some relevelance part of your code.

Comment: public class ViEwS4LiFeApp extends WebViewClient
    {
     @Override
     public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
      super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      progressWheel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   
     }
    }